# Passing Delegate to Sort()

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, delegates

In the book "Functional C#" by  Enrico Buonanno, on page 16, the following Code was given:

```
namespace System
{
    public delegate int Comparison<in T>(T x, T y);
}

var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => i * 3).ToList();
list // => [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30]
Comparison<int> alphabetically = (l, r)
=> l.ToString().CompareTo(r.ToString());
list.Sort(alphabetically);
list // => [12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 3, 30, 6, 9]
```

This, however, when executed in the REPL, doesn't yield anything useful.

```
error CS1503: Argument "1": Konvertierung von "Comparison<int>" in "System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<int>" nicht möglich.
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: What error is that in English?

Comment: "Conversion of `Comparison<int>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<int>` is not possible". What version of C#/.Net are you trying this in?

Comment: Currently, .Net6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Comparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=net-6.0) is an existing delegate in .NET so you don't need to declare your own. Just remove this declaration and corresponding [`List.Sort(Comparison<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-sort(system-comparison((-0)))) will be invoked - compare [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyAMABMugHQAyYAdgI4DcOOyAzEagQMI4DeOBfRLZABYCAWQAUASl78e2fgoIA3AIYAnAhDABnYAQC8BAKKUArgFsApmpUAjCJZIAlFZQDml8eigF0eSSQAypYOAMbA4mAGAHwEUQBUBEwBACoA9hS6UvTyinzsaeYADuo6aZQAPFTAsSoQRQAWdpbAYKF1EACeBgTi0ARqkjGaJOmBwGpUblIkBcXqluniaqNp45PuUpI5eXxaukFpahF1jc2t7RBd2zJ8AL44D9g4lCpW2iWhlkRY2HIKzAIMBCljcKmA32qHEKJUm2nKVUoBBS0XEKQIAA8fOjOjdsE8gA=) and [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBkCWAdgI4DcyyUAzJjOgMLIDey6bmNUALOgLIAUASlbsWSdhPQA3AIYAndABt8AZwAu6ALzoAooQCuAWwCmcmQCNFx7ACUZhAObH+cADTo4qQdgDKxqwDGavz4WgB86KEAVOhU3gAqAPYE6kLk4pJs9ImGAA7yqomEADxEahEyirkAFhbGavgBlYoAnlro/IrucoLhSthJPmpyRA5C2Nl58sZJ/HIDiUMjjkKC6Zlsyuq+iXLBlTV1DU2KrWsibAC+yJdAA==).